# Kubernetes - MountVolume.NewMounter initialization failed for volume "<volume-name>" : path does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I am trying to setup a Local Persistent volume using local storage using WSL. But the pod STATUS stops at **Pending**.

The `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>` gives below error.

`Warning  FailedMount       21s (x7 over 53s)    kubelet            MountVolume.NewMounter initialization failed for volume "pv1" : path "/mnt/data" does not exist`

The path `/mnt/data` has been created and exists on the local machine but cannot be accessed by the container.

and the pod and Persistent volume configuration as below.

```
apiVersion : v1
kind : PersistentVolume
metadata :
   name : pv1
spec :
  capacity :
    storage : 2Gi
  accessModes :
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy : Retain
  storageClassName : local-storage
  local : 
    fsType : ext4
    path : /mnt/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node1

---

apiVersion : v1
kind : PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata : 
  name : pvc1
spec :
  resources :
    requests :
      storage : 1Gi
  accessModes :
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName : local-storage

---

apiVersion : v1
kind : Pod
metadata :
  name : pod1
spec :
  containers:
  - name: www
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
        name: www
    volumeMounts:
      - name: www-store
        mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumes :
    - name : www-store
      persistentVolumeClaim :
        claimName : pvc1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `nodeSelector` for the `pv`, telling it to use `node1` for the volume , **chances are** 1. `node1` does not have `/mnt/data` directory present, which is    `hostPath` for the volume.
**OR** 2. `node1` may be having `/mnt/data`, but the `pod` is getting scheduled on some other node which does not have `/mnt/data`    directory:

```
apiVersion : v1
kind : PersistentVolume
metadata :
   name : pv1
spec :
  capacity :
    storage : 2Gi
  accessModes :
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy : Retain
  storageClassName : local-storage
  local : 
    fsType : ext4
    path : /mnt/data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - node1
```

**Solution:**
Make sure `/mnt/data` is present on all schedulable nodes

**OR**

Try modifying your file to add, `nodeName` or `nodeSelector` or `nodeAffinity` to force it to get scheduled on the same node  which have proper hostPath. In below example, it is assumed that `node1` have `/mnt/data` directory present.

```
apiVersion : v1
kind : Pod
metadata :
  name : pod1
spec :
  nodeName: node1 #<------------this
  containers:
  - name: www
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
        name: www
    volumeMounts:
      - name: www-store
        mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumes :
    - name : www-store
      persistentVolumeClaim :
        claimName : pvc1
```

Answer (score 9):

If running on a Rancher Kubernetes Engine (RKE) cluster, this problem can arise from the fact that each kubelet also runs as a container. Thus, it does not see the filesystem of the node it runs on.

The solution is to add extra bind mounts (for `kubelet` service) when configuring the cluster in `cluster.yml`. For example, to have `/data-1` on the node to be mounted as `/data-1` on the kubelet:

```yaml
services:
  ...
  kubelet: 
    extra_binds:
    - "/data-1:/data-1"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Great tip, it made me think, for me I realised that microk8s had a host path storage plugin which had a default path: https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-hostpath-storage

Answer (score 1):

On [Talos](https://www.talos.dev/) which similarly to the Rancher Kubernetes Engine (RKE) from the other answer also runs the `kubelet` containerized, one must [configure](https://www.talos.dev/v1.2/reference/configuration/#kubeletconfig)
`extraMounts` in the `MachineConfig.kubelet`, e.g. like this:

```
extraMounts:
  - destination: /var/mnt/nvme1
    type: bind
    source: /var/mnt/nvme1
    options:
      - bind
      - rshared
      - rw
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rancher-Desktop(Windows) and facing the same issue
i.e. `Warning  FailedMount       21s (x7 over 53s)    kubelet            MountVolume.NewMounter initialization failed for volume "pv1": path "/mnt/data" does not exist`

As per the below document, *'For Windows, all files are automatically shared via WSL2.'*
https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/faq/#q-does-file-sharing-work-similarly-to-docker-desktop-do-i-have-to-do-any-additional-configuration-to-mount-volumes-to-vms

So you can create the directory inside any of the drives eg. `C:` or `D:`
and during specifying the path in YAML you should prefix with `/mnt`

for example: suppose you created a directory inside `D:` drive let's say, `D:\data`

Now path will be like this - `/mnt/d/data`